# how to delete the expired data from database (depends on a period column)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I want to delete the data that expired.

**I have two columns:**
`created_time` : That contain a value indicate to `time()` function `(ex: 1395836716)`.
`period` :That contain the period of the remain the row in database `(ex: 3 or 7 or 15 or 30 per day)`.

I want to create a query to check on all rows in the table to know the rows that expired.
The problem is  I don't know how to do that, but I tried.

```
$twentyFour = 60 * 60 * 24;
mysql_query("DELETE FROM content WHERE created_time + (period * $twentyFour ) > '" . time() . "' ");
```

But unfortunately, did not work as I expected.

---

**Edit:**

This is a result of row

[image]

---

**Edit 2**

I did it, by using php conditions:

```
$twentyFour = 60 * 60 * 24;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if ($data['created_time'] + ($data['period'] * $twentyFour) < time()) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM content WHERE id = $data[id]");
    }
}
```

The previous code works fine as was I want.
the problem is the previous code will occurs more server load.
I want a query to doing as the previous code does without using conditions.

Comment: DELETE FROM content WHERE  created_time +  (period * $twentyFour ) < now()

Comment: Please define "does not work" - lack of specifics are so unhelpful. Note that in the question you indicate the field is a timestamp, but the image (not sure what it is supposed to mean) uses dates. Please give specific examples of records that are deleted/not-deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest you edit your data structure and include a new column `delete_time`?

This `delete_time` should contain the UNIX timestamp of when your column should be deleted calculated from your given `period`.

---

Assuming your POST data of the `period` is numerical value indicating the number of days to save the data for, `delete_time` should be calculated by

```
$delete_time = time() + $_POST['period']*24*60*60;
```

This way, your pruning/deleting query can just be a one-liner:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM content WHERE delete_time < ".time());
```

That query deletes all rows whose `delete_time` has passed the current `time()`.

Comment: I think this is not bad idea thank you, if I did not find another alternative solution I will use it, and I will give your answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM content 
WHERE created_time < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL `period` DAY)
```

Comment: What about the value of `period`. `period` is that determine the period of remain the row in database.

Comment: I'm going to need you to explain exactly what role that plays as I am not quite sure how it will affect what you are doing here. Basically, i don't know what "the period of remain the row in database" means

Comment: For example:
I want to add new ad, there is a dropdown menu to determine the period of display the ad, (3 days, 7 days, 15 days, 30 days). for example  I will select 7 days from dropdown menu, then I will click on insert button to store the data in database. the `created_time` column will store the time now by using time() function, also the `period` column will store the value of dropdown menu, in this case will store 7, because I have selected 7 day. that's it . I hope that you may understand me.

Comment: Unfortunately, still does not deletes the correct data.

Comment: Does it delete any data? Do you know how to set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? If you could set one up that would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same result, note: I'm use `SELECT` statement instead delete at now.

Comment: is: created_time always less than NOW() anyway? should the test look something  like now() < date_add(create_time, interval `period` day) which will be false until the expiry date? date_sub may be useful given what you have. I hate dates :-/ i need to setup some test data.

Comment: I think you meant date_sub - right now the where clause looks to be where created <  Inthefuture. Which is ~always true.

Comment: I find it interesting that at least two people liked the answer so much that they endorsed it by upvoting it. Even though the answer doesn't work. just curious as to what they were thinking when they stopped by to upvote the answer.

Comment: Thank you for continue help me, Please see my update in my question (Edit 2).

Answer (score 0):

See edit2: of the question

Given that times are held as unix timestamps this is what is required:

```
 DELETE FROM content 
 WHERE (created_time + period * 60 * 60 * 24) <= NOW()
```

here is the: **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/147b4a/1)**

I had forgotten how much fun playing with dates and times in SQL wasn't ;-/

```
----------------------------------------
```

If using 'real' **DateTime** columns then this is the way to go:

Use:

```
 DELETE FROM content 
 WHERE created_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `period` DAY)
```

or:

```
DELETE from content
WHERE NOW() > DATE_ADD(`created_time`, INTERVAL `period` DAY)
```

Dates and date differences are always difficult to get right. The issue is that you need to pick a reference point:

```
1) NOW() against created_at + interval, 
2) NOW() against  `expiry_date
3) created_at + interval against NOW()
4) expiry_date against NOW().
```

that while you try and work it out, you tend to switch the reference point and it is very non-intuitive.

I have created an SQL Fiddle that demonstrates all the calculations. The 'created_at' date is always midnight to 'simplify' the checking. You can change the variable called 'is_now' and see the result of all the date differences and the boolean results. It is 'interesting', maybe.

**TL;DR**

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd1580/29)** gives the correct answer.

Comment: @Lion King, i should have added tl;dr at at the start of my answer :-)

Comment: Notice: `created_time` value is UNIXTIME like this `1395912075` -> the value of `time()` funciton that returned. also the type of `created_time` column is `INT` not `datetime` .

Comment: @Lion King, thanks for the tips. made me see how to tidy my sqlfiddle.

Comment: Thank you for continue help me, Please see my update in my question (`Edit 2`).